# How to use certificates from weblogic realm keystores inside web application?

Tags: java, cryptography, weblogic

I'm doing some security operations involving certificates in my web application and I would like administrators to manage those certificates (including password etc.) via standard weblogic console. However I don't know how to obtain certificates set in weblogic in web application running in that weblogic. Is it even supported feature? Is it possible to connect it with standard java cryptographic api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Weblogic, There is one `Mbean` with name `com.oracle.jps:type=JpsKeyStore`. You can check the operations to find one to fulfill you requirements. I think in most of the cases, you can find one.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to update KeyStores in weblogic(Admin console, WLST online, WLST offline).

**Admin console**

> Environment--> servers--> 'your server' --> KeyStores , Then update the related
>   parameters

**WLST offline(Script Mode)**

```
readDomain(domainDir)
cd("/Servers/" + msName)
set("KeyStores", "CustomIdentityAndCustomTrust")
set("CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName", identKeystoreFile)
set("CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted", identKeystoreKSPass)
set("CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName", trustKeystoreFile)
set("CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted", trustKeystoreKSPass)
updateDomain()
exit()
```

**WLST online(Script Mode)**

```
connect(username,password,"t3://localhost:7001")
cd("/Servers/" + msName)
set("KeyStores", "CustomIdentityAndCustomTrust")
set("CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName", identKeystoreFile)
set("CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted", encrypt(inp_identKeystoreKSPass))
set("CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName", inp_trustKeystoreFile)
set("CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted", encrypt(inp_trustKeystoreKSPass))
save()
activate()
```

**WLST online(Embedded Mode)**

```
InteractiveInterpreter interpreter = new WLSTInterpreter();
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:7001')\n"); 
buffer.append("cd('/Servers/' + msName)\n");
buffer.append("set('KeyStores', 'CustomIdentityAndCustomTrust')\n");
buffer.append("set('CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName', identKeystoreFile)\n");
buffer.append("set('CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted', encrypt(inp_identKeystoreKSPass))\n");
buffer.append("set('CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName', inp_trustKeystoreFile)\n");
buffer.append("set('CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted', encrypt(inp_trustKeystoreKSPass))\n");
buffer.append("save()\n");
buffer.append("activate()");
interpreter.exec(buffer.toString());
```